# Apache Beam get source File Name

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**EDIT: RESOLVED!**

I have multiple Text files from multiple languages. I want to add a language tag to each line using Apache Beam.

**Example:**

File *text_en*:
`This is a sentence.`

File *text_de*: `Dies ist ein Satz.`

What I want is this:

```
en: This is a sentence.
de: Dies ist ein Satz.
```

**What I've tried:**

I initially tried to just use one `TextIO.Read.From(dataSetDirectory+"/*")` and look for an option that looks something like `.getSource()`. However, this doesn't seem to exist.

Next I tried to read every File one by one like this:

```
File[] files = new File(datasetDirectory).listFiles();
PCollectionList<String> dataSet=null;
for (File f: files) {
   String language = f.getName();
   logger.debug(language);
   PCollection<String> newPCollection = p.apply(
            TextIO.Read.from(f.getAbsolutePath()))
               .apply(ParDo.of(new LanguageTagAdder(language)));

   if (dataSet==null) {
       dataSet=PCollectionList.of(newPCollection);
   } else {
       dataSet.and(newPCollection);
   }
}
PCollection<String> completeDataset= dataSet.apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections())
```

Reading the Files this way works perfectly fine, however my DoFn `LanguageTagAdder` is only initialized with the first language, thus all Files have the same added language.

`LanguageTagAdder` looks like this:

```
public class LanguageTagAdder
            extends DoFn<String,String> {

        private String language;
        public LanguageTagAdder(String language) {
            this.language=language;
        }
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            c.output(language+c.element());
        }
    }
```

I realize this behavior is intended and needed so that the data can be parrallelized, but how would I go about solving my Problem? Is there a *Beam*-way to solve it?

PS: I get following warnings when creating a `new LanguageTagAdder` for the second time (with a second language):

```
DEBUG   2016-12-05 17:09:55,070 [main] de.kdld16.hpi.FusionDataset  - en
DEBUG   2016-12-05 17:09:56,216 [main] de.kdld16.hpi.FusionDataset  - de
WARN    2016-12-05 17:09:56,219 [main] org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline  - Transform TextIO.Read2 does not have a stable unique name. This will prevent updating of pipelines.
```

**EDIT:**
The Problem was the line

`dataSet.and(newPCollection);`

It needed to be rewritten as:

`dataSet=dataSet.and(newPCollection);`

The way it was, dataSet only contained the first File.... No wonder they all had the same language Tag!

Comment: Your example with "Next I tried to read every File one by one like this:" should work, and it is currently the easiest way in Beam to achieve what you want. Can you give more details about how you spotted that LanguageTagAdder gets initialized with only the first language? Your code is creating different instances of LanguageTagAdder, and Beam should be using them as-is: are you saying that's not what's happening in practice?

Comment: Also, which runner are you using? If it's not DirectRunner: does the problem reproduce in DirectRunner?

Comment: I am using the DirectRunner. Many LanguageTagAdders are initialized (with many different languages), I can see that when I put breakpoints in the constructor. However, every line in every Text file only has the same language Tag "en".


```Your code is creating different instances of LanguageTagAdder, and Beam should be using them as-is: are you saying that's not what's happening in practice?```

Yes this is exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my issue. Thanks for letting me know that what I tried should work though!

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was the line

```
dataSet.and(newPCollection);
```

It needed to be rewritten as:

```
dataSet=dataSet.and(newPCollection);
```

The way it was, dataSet only contained the first File.